# How to find the longest English Word that can be displayed in a seven segment display?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, nested-loops

I was inspired from Tom Scott's Video about seven segment displays (link Below), and set out to find out the longest english word that can be displayed in a seven segment display using python, I am a beginner and the best code I could write was this:

```
var1=open("c:/Users/Choutisha Banerjee/Desktop/words.txt", "r")
list1=var1.readlines()
list2 = ["g","k","m","q","v","w","x","z"]
longword=" "
for n in list1:
    if len(n)>len(longword):
        for x in n:
         if x in list2:
             continue
        else:
             longword=n
    else:
        continue
    print(longword)
```

It is printing the longest word present in the list. It would be a great help if you could inform me about where I went wrong.

(I used a premade list of all english words i.e. words.txt)

Link to Tom's Video: https://youtu.be/zp4BMR88260

link to .py (just in case you need it): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M78YP67VkqC2Uz3mbQxcqk15vO7mW6Rx/view?usp=sharing

Please Help
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
words_file = open("words.txt", "r")
words = words_file.read().lower().splitlines()
letter_list = ["g", "k", "m", "q", "v", "w", "x", "z"]
seven_segment_words = []


def word_checker(word):
    word_contains_aloud_letters = not any(letter in word for letter in letter_list)
    if word_contains_aloud_letters:
        seven_segment_words.append(word)


for word in words:
    word_checker(word)

longest_seven_segmented_word = max(seven_segment_words, key=len)
print(longest_seven_segmented_word)
```

you were looking if each individual letter was in the list or not, you had to look at them all at ones

Comment: It would be a great help, if you could bother to explain a little bit more, as I am a beginner, and don't get the Def part, read.lower.splitlines, etc. Please help if you can?

Comment: @AmitabhBachan well the def part is not really needed its just that i think it looks better and im addicted to using defs. if you dont want the def, you can just move it over to the for loop and it will do the same. if you dont know what a def is you might want to look on here [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp).

read basically reads the entire file, lower makes all the characters lowercase so you program still works if it has a uppercase character and splitlines just splits the string on every newline.

Comment: if you still dont get why i did certain things they way i did, feel free to contact me on discord: Bjorn#5856

Comment: Thank you very much, that was really helpful.